# List settings > adding Columns > Yes/No or drop down

Tags: infopath, column

I created an InfoPath form for policy acceptance. Initially I set a column in the list as boolean (Yes/No) whether users accept or denied the policy. But now the business unit wants a third category "accept with exceptions".

So should I change yes/no column to drop down store the value. I am thinking store 3 different values (accept, denied, accept w/exceptions).

Is that the best design? Need your opinion. Or there are better ways to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the right choice.

Boolean columns are very inflexible. Even for Yes/No options, I find that creating a choice column is a better option.

Comment: I concur with Christophe, I always use a choice field instead of boolean even if its just Yes/No values.